# CakePHP core tests not working on IIS

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, testing, cakephp-2.0, automated-tests

I'm following the steps (from http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html) to set up Testing on a CakePHP install.

Viewing the core tests is supposed to be as simple as appending /test.php to my application's URL. But when I do that, I get an error page, saying...

> Missing Controller
>
> Error: Test.phpController could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class Test.phpController below in file:
>   my-app\Controller\Test.phpController.php

Obviously, "test.php" is supposed to be a real file, not the name of a controller, so I think either my IIS rewrites might be incorrect, or maybe some setting in test.php itself? I haven't found anything useful elsewhere on the Internet so I'm asking here.

(By the way, my app works pretty well, but I didn't install it from scratch -- a colleague created the app initially, so I can't swear that all the defaults are set as they would be on an out-of-the-box CakePHP installation.)

Answer (score 0):

The fix for my problem was twofold. First, rather than appending `test.php`, I had to append `webroot/test.php`. Then I had to deactivate "Imported Rule 3" from CakePHP's [URL rewrites on IIS7](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html#url-rewrites-on-iis7-windows-hosts). This rule says:

```
<match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="app/webroot/{R:1}" />
```

I am not sure why that rewrite rule was included, but it doesn't seem to be necessary, and it prevents test.php from working.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue but your solution doesn't seem to work for me. Also, the rules I have are a bit different I think. I just imported them using IIS 7.