# Using PHPUnit with CakePHP on IIS 7 over Windows

Tags: cakephp, iis-7, phpunit, cakephp-2.2

I am having troubles trying to make PHPUnit work over IIS 7 and Windows 7.
I am getting this error when trying to test if it works accessing to `http://localhost/your_app/test.php` [as pointed in the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#checking-the-test-setup):

> Missing Controller
>
> Error: Test.php&debug=1Controller could not be found. Error: Create
>   the class Test.php&debug=1Controller below in file:
>   app\Controller\Test.php&debug=1Controller.php
>
> }
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app\View\Errors\missing_controller.ctp Stack Trace
>   APP\webroot\index.php line 92 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest,
>   CakeResponse) ROOT\index.php line 42 → require(string)

I have been lookin at [this other topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16309260/cakephp-core-tests-not-working-on-iis) but his solution doesn't work for me.

I have installed Pear using this commands:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.6.4
```

And it seems it has been installed successfully:
[image]

I have edited `php.ini`, and added the the `pear` directory to the `include_path`:

```
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
include_path = ".;c:\php\pear"
```

My rewrite rules on IIS 7 are the following ones ( I just imported them in IIS from the .htaccess files):
[image]

It seems to be a rewrite rule problem as it seems to be looking for a controller when it shouldn't.

Any idea about how to solve this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I had to disable the last 2 rules on the "URL Rewrite" at IIS 7 and then access to the following URL:
`http://localhost/cakephp/app/webroot/test.php`

[image]